# Structuring code logic for events on laravel controller

Tags: javascript, php, ecmascript-6, laravel, vue.js

The code below will store a base64 image on another website and create an event to display the image on a Vue page in *real time*. It works fine and all.

My question is, is this a good way of doing it or there's a better way to structure the code? I've thought about placing the logic in a listener but it doesn't seem that I need to use one. For queues, I'll add them later on.

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $base64 = $request->image;
    $image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64);
    $imageName = 'draw'.time().'.png';
    $response = $this->guzzleClient()->post(config('archiving.api_postBase64_file'),
        [  
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'file',
                    'contents' => $image
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'file_name',
                    'contents' => $imageName
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'file_folder',
                    'contents' => 'drawings'
                ],
            ],
        ]
    );
    if($response->getStatusCode() >= 500){
        return response($response->getBody(), $response->getStatusCode());
    }else{
        $drawing = Drawing::create([
            'user_id'=>Auth::id(),
            'file_name'=>$imageName,
        ]);
        event(new NewDrawing($drawing));
        return response('Drawing created!',200);
    }
}
```

**NewDrawing Event**

```
class NewDrawing implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $drawing;

    public function __construct(Drawing $drawing)
    {
        $this->drawing = $drawing;
    }
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('channel-drawing');
    }
 }
```

**Frontend (Vue)**

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            images:'',
        }
    },
    methods:{
        listen() {
            Echo.channel('channel-drawing')
            .listen('NewDrawing', res => {
                this.images.push(res.drawing);
            })  
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.listen()
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Always OR Never use semis at end of statements. Either is fine but be consistent. You can always implement a strict linter to keep your code quality high.

Comment: Your question title describes your concern, but it is expected to uniquely describe what your script does.

Answer (score 4):

I'm mostly a back-end guy who fusses his way through front end code. Here's my advice:

- Keep the controller code as close as possible to handling the response only. Delegate the creation of objects to their own classes. Think of the S in SOLID - Single Responsibility.

  ```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
      $image = new ImageMeta($base64);
      $archiver = new ImageArchiver($image);
      $response = $archiver->post();

      if($response->getStatusCode() >= 500){
          return response($response->getBody(), $response->getStatusCode());
      }else{
          $drawing = Drawing::create([
              'user_id'=>Auth::id(),
              'file_name'=>$imageName,
          ]);
          //There's a few different ways to look at this which might be part of a larger conversation, 
          // so I won't touch this part yet. But is this something specific to drawings? Or is the broadcast
          // of model creation something that will happen for lots of different models? Regardless, I would 
          // change the name from NewDrawing to something like DrawingCreationBroadcast, or something like that
          // NewDrawing gets confusing since its too close to new Drawing();
          event(new NewDrawing($drawing));
          return response('Drawing created!',200);
      }
   }
  ```

ImageMeta class

```
    /** For all classes assume property declarations, and getters are included. 
    * Lean toward immutable classes where possible, so don't include setters 
    * unless it becomes necessary. Code re-use != object instance re-use.
    **/

    class ImageMeta {
        public function __construct($base64) {
            $this->image = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64);
            $this->imageName = 'draw'.time().'.png';
        }
    }
```

ImageArchiver class

```
    class ImageArchiver {
        private $config;
        
        public function __construct(ImageMeta $image) {
            $this->image = $image;
            $this->makeConfig();
        }
        
        private function makeConfig() {
            $this->config = [  
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'file',
                        'contents' => $image->getImage()
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'file_name',
                        'contents' => $imageName->getName()
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'file_folder',
                        'contents' => 'drawings'
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        }
        
        //use type hinting here. Off the top of my head I don't know the parent class of guzzleClient
        public function archive($guzzleClient) {
            return $guzzleClient->post($this->config);
        }

    }
```

Comment: where should i store the ImageMeta and ImageArchiever class file ?

Comment: my bad, so ur suggesting to use service right ?

Comment: I'm not necessarily suggesting a service, but it might make sense depending on how often this is used.

Put it where it makes sense. I don't just dump everything into a models folder, but use the Models folder as the root of all classes.

Answer (score 1):

In [this presentation about cleaning up code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtB5DAfOWMQ) Rafael Dohms talks about many ways to keep code lean - like avoiding the `else` keyword. ([see the slides here](https://www.slideshare.net/rdohms/bettercode-phpbenelux212alternate/11-OC_1Only_one_indentation_level)).

It is wise to avoid the `else` keyword - especially when it isn't needed - e.g. when a previous block contains a `return` statement:

> ```
>    if($response->getStatusCode() >= 500){
>        return response($response->getBody(), $response->getStatusCode());
>    }else{
>        $drawing = Drawing::create([
>            'user_id'=>Auth::id(),
>            'file_name'=>$imageName,
>        ]);
>        event(new NewDrawing($drawing));
>        return response('Drawing created!',200);
>    }
> ```

---

In the Frontend code, it appears that `images` is set to an empty string:

> ```
>  data(){
>    return{
>        images:'',
>    }
> },
> ```

Yet in the listen callback it is used like an array:

> ```
>        Echo.channel('channel-drawing')
>        .listen('NewDrawing', res => {
>            this.images.push(res.drawing);
>        })
> ```

It should be initialized as an array in `data()`.

Is the method `listen()` called anywhere other than the `mounted()` callback? If not, then it may be simpler just to move the code from that method into the `mounted()` callback.